# Not able to install any package in Redhat linux

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum

I'm trying to install php or any other package getting below issue

```
[root@xxxxxx xxxxx]# yum install php
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin
This system is receiving updates from Spacewalk server.


Repository ol7_addons is listed more than once in the configuration
```